# Use didSelectRowAtIndexPath or prepareForSegue method for UITableView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, storyboard

I'm using storyboards and I have a UITableView.  I have a segue setup that pushes from my table to the detail VC.  But which method should I use to handle this?  I'll have to pass a couple objects to the detail view.  But do I use `didSelectRowAtIndex` or `-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender`?

Answer (score 199, accepted):

If you use `prepareForSegue:sender:`then you won't have as much to change if you later decide to trigger the segue from some control outside the table view.

The `prepareForSegue:sender:` message is sent to the current view controller, so I'd suggest something like this:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    // Assume self.view is the table view
    NSIndexPath *path = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
    DetailObject *detail = [self detailForIndexPath:path];
    [segue.destinationViewController setDetail:detail];
}
```

In Swift:

```swift
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    let path = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow()!
    segue.destinationViewController.detail = self.detailForIndexPath(path)
}
```

Comment: Ok, can you give an example of how to implement it with passing an object based on indexPath.

Comment: shouldn't `self.view` be just be `sender` here? I couldn't even get `[self.view indexPathForSelectedRow]` to work, I had to do `[sender indexPathForSelectedRow];`

Comment: How would you do this in Swift?

Comment: @robmayoff Thanks for updating this for Swift. I made some slight edits to reflect recent language changes. Hope this helps some others

Comment: It is weird that `tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow()` contains the correct value when `prepareFroSegue...` is called: `tableView(_:didSelectrowAtIndexPath:)` isn't called until later.

Answer (score 5):

I did this and it worked

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    NSLog(@"Row Selected = %i",indexPath.row);

    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"testID" sender:self.view];    
}
```

Comment: That doesn't make sense. You should either use the segue OR the table view delegate. 
Just create a segue from the Cell and it will automatically perform the same thing you did without writing code.

Comment: how do you assign a segue to a cell without didSelectRow?

Answer (score 3):

When sender is UITableViewCell, you may ask UITableView to query indexPath of the cell.

```
    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        if let cell = sender as? UITableViewCell {
            let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForCell(cell)!
            assert(segue.destinationViewController.isKindOfClass(DetailViewController))
            let detailViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! DetailViewController
            detailViewController.item = self.items[indexPath.row] // like this
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

if your tableView property is in another class and you **only have one section**, then you could use the `tag` property to store the cell's row like:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

     UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];

     cell.tag = indexPath.row;

     return cell;
}
```

And then you can access it as the `sender` is the same cell with the row value in its tag:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {

    MyDestinationViewController *destinationViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
    destinationViewController.myProperty = [tableViewElementsArray objectAtIndex:[sender tag]]; // sender will be your cell 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow` returns selected cell, but not segue sender cell, e.g. sender cell is not selected (accessory action), or in multiple selection case. The best way is getting indexPath for segue sender:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    __auto_type itemViewController = (id<ItemViewController>)segue.destinationViewController;
    itemViewController.senderIndexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:sender];
}
```

In Swift:

```
protocol ItemViewController {
    var senderIndexPath : IndexPath? { get set }
    var selectedIndexPaths : [IndexPath]? { get set }
}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if  let cell = sender as? UITableViewCell,
        var itemViewController = segue.destination as? ItemViewController {
        itemViewController.senderIndexPath = tableView.indexPath(for: cell)
        itemViewController.selectedIndexPaths = tableView.indexPathsForSelectedRows
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use `prepareForSegue:` you can check who is the sender and execute different code

For example in swift

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UiStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?)
{
   var senderIsTableviewCell:Bool! = sender?.isKindOfClass(UITableViewCell)

   if senderIsTableviewCell
   {
       //do something
   }
}
```

Comment: Just do: *if let tableViewCell = sender as? UITableViewCell { // do something }*. If sender can't be cast to a UITableViewCell, "do something" won't execute.