# Unwanted double navigation bar

Tags: iphone, xcode, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I made the navigation bar (top bar) appear/disappear when I tap the screen, and also lay on top of the background image. It worked, but with one problem: I've suddenly got two navigation bars! First, one with a back button named "Back", and when I press "Back" it pops up a new navigation bar with a back button named "Vinene", which is the title of the TableView it leads back to. Thats the one I want to keep. I think the issue is somewhere in the DetailViewController.m or in the didselectrowatindexpath in the MasterViewController.m. Hope someone can see the problem!

DetailViewController.m:

```
@interface WinesDetailViewController ()

@end

@implementation WinesDetailViewController

@synthesize wineDictionary;

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
if (self) {
    // Custom initialization
}
return self;
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
[super viewDidAppear:animated];

}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view.

self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = YES;
                         self.wantsFullScreenLayout = YES;

UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(hideShowNavigation)] autorelease];
                                                                                                         tap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
                                                                                                 [self.view addGestureRecognizer:tap];
}

- (void) hideShowNavigation
{
[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:!self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden];
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
[super viewDidUnload];
// Release any retained subviews of the main view.
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}

- (BOOL)hidesBottomBarWhenPushed{
return TRUE;
}


@end
```

MasterViewController.m:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
    {
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];    

    NSDictionary *dictionary = [wine libraryItemAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    if (winesDetailViewController == nil) {
        // Init the wine detail view
        winesDetailViewController = [[WinesDetailViewController alloc] init];
    }
    // Here you pass the dictionary
    winesDetailViewController.wineDictionary = dictionary;

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:winesDetailViewController animated:YES];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usually, a recurring navigation bar like you describe is caused by something like pushing the same view controller twice. Can you check to ensure you're only pushing a single view controller on to your navigation stack (via breakpoints or logging?). Is it possible that winesDetailViewController is already on the navigation stack? You can also try logging the value of `self.navigationController.viewControllers` for a hint.

I would also suggest moving

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = YES;
```

to viewWillAppear and

```
self.wantsFullScreenLayout = YES;
```

to your initializer (though I don't think this will solve your problem).

Comment: I guess thats the problem, it sounds logic. I try to pass som data from a tableview to a detail view but it's tricky because I'm new to this. I've made a storyboard connection from the prototype cell to the detail view in the storyboard, and in the didselectrowatindexpath code that I posted in my question. It works fine so far except th double bar.

Comment: If you're using a storyboard in that way, you probably want to use something like this question suggests; don't push your own detail view controller. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8130600/use-didselectrowatindexpath-or-prepareforsegue-method-for-uitableview