# Extra UINavigationBar showing in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uibutton, uinavigationbar

I have an issue With UINavigationBar , when i add UIButton over there and when i run the application i can see one extra UINaviagtionBar overlay on top of my UINavigationBar.

Please help

The structure is like

UITabbarController -> UINavigationController -->UIViewController

I have attached screen shots link

**Run time**[![[1]][1]][1]

**Xcode** [image]

[navigationcontroller->viewcontroller screen][3]

Code

ViewDidAppear()

```
UIImage *myImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"filter.png"];
UIButton *myButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[myButton setImage:myImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
myButton.showsTouchWhenHighlighted = YES;
myButton.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0,25,25);
[myButton addTarget:self action:@selector(refreshSection) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
UIBarButtonItem *rightButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:myButton];
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = rightButton;

UIImage *myImage1 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Contacts.png"];
UIButton *myButton1 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[myButton1 setImage:myImage1 forState:UIControlStateNormal];
myButton1.showsTouchWhenHighlighted = YES;
myButton1.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0,30,30);

[myButton1 addTarget:self action:@selector(profile) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

UIBarButtonItem *rightButton1 = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:myButton1];
[self.navigationItem setRightBarButtonItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:rightButton1, nil]];
```

[full screen storyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BhxFU.png)

Comment: Please post a better screenshot of your xcode project. Have you embedded your view controller in a Navigation Contoller? Or are you manually adding a navigation bar into the View controller?

Comment: yes, embedded with uinavigation controller

Comment: See if this thread is of any help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11199227/unwanted-double-navigation-bar

Comment: ok sure let me check

Answer (score 0):

I think code is correct just set contentMode property.

[[myButton imageView] setContentMode: UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit];

Same for other buttons.

Comment: No, I can see one more transparent uinavigationbar on top of my existingbar

Comment: Add [[UINavigationBar appearance] setTranslucent:NO];    in applicationDidfinshLaunchingWithOption

Comment: But UITababrController and UINavigationController are added in Storyboard not via code

Comment: after your code i can see black color below my uinavigationbar

Answer (score 0):

Go to your root navigation controller, select the navigation bar and under the Attributes Inspector, make sure you have:

1. Default style,
2. Translucent option enabled,
3. Default bar tint.

Comment: i will give you my storyboard full image here..please help me

Comment: i need to use this code [self.navigationController pushViewController:health animated:YES];   so i need a UINavigationController embedded