# Double navigation bar

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift, uinavigationbar

Here is my unwanted double navigation bars:

[image]

In storyboard, the link is like this:

1. A segue from the tabbar controller to this friendzone viewController
2. friendzone VC is embedded in a navigation controller.

My navigation controller top bar is set to inferred, and friendzone VC top bar is set to hidden. I have removed all kinds of configuration to the navigation bar(like navigationItem.leftbarbutton, translucent  etc). There are four other tabItems in the tab bar controller, where three of them is embedded in a navigation controller. I have found similar problems on stackoverflow, but none of the answers is working for this case.

Update: The only code I have in friendZone viewcontroller considering the navigation bar is this in viewWillAppear():

```
self.navigationController?.toolbarHidden = true
self.navigationController!.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(colorImage,forBarMetrics: UIBarMetrics.Default)
self.navigationController!.navigationBar.shadowImage = colorImage
self.navigationController!.navigationBar.translucent = true
```

Update: An image of the [storyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EoyaS.png). If I subclass my navigation controller and call this in viewDidLoad:

```
self.setViewControllers([homeViewController], animated: true)
```

so the homeViewController first gets loaded by storyboard segue, then with code the first homeViewController will have double navigation bar, but the second have just one

Comment: Can you please add screen shot of your storyboard.

Comment: Can you take a zoomed out screenshot of your storyboard? That way we can recreate your setup.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue using a tabbarcontroller and a navigation controller.

The storyboard editor doesn't change anything when you change things there. At runtime test options won't be validated.

What i did:

```
self.navigationController?.toolbarHidden = true
```

In your `viewDidLoad()`

Comment: when i set toolbarHidden = true there is still 2 navigation bars!

Comment: Can you try to set status bar to none in the simulated metrics ?

Comment: If I set the Navigation controllers´ top bar to none, none of them is visible

Comment: You have somewhere where you add it twice? Can you update and post your code ?

Comment: No I dont think I do. But it seems to be a problem with the translucent = true. If i set the navigation bar to opaque, and then back to inferred in storyboard, i get only one bar. If i set to translucent and then back to inferred i get two. So strange... Opaque is working, sadly i want translucency

Comment: Can you check if you extend your edges under  top bars ? It is in the same right hand menu as the display metrics. In de veiwcontroller section, you will see a checkbox with extend edges under top bars. Is it checked?

Comment: it is checked in both the viewcontroller and in the navigation controller.

Comment: i don't manage to find it myself and i can't recreate your problem... Someone with the same problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11199227/unwanted-double-navigation-bar

Comment: Thanks for trying! Ive tried printing self.navigationcontroller.viewcontrollers, and it only prints one VC